# Product of variables

Tags: probability

> Suppose we have a set of variables $\{a_i,b_i| i=1,2,3\}$ which can take values $\pm 1$ according to some probabilities.
>
> If there's a constraint that $a_1b_2b_3=a_2b_1b_3=a_3b_1b_2$ must equal to $1$, why then must the value of $$a_1a_2a_3=1$$?

I thought of saying that $a_1b_2b_3a_2b_1b_3a_3b_1b_2=a_1a_2a_3(b_1b_2b_3)^2=1$ therefore the result follows, but I don't think this argument is valid, since the first $b_1$ may differ from the second. -- they are variables and since there is a non-zero probability for both $\pm 1$...

Also, I don't understand why we couldn't have $$a_1=a_2=+1, a_3=-1$$ and have the $\{b_i\}$'s take appropriate values -- since there is a probability, it's possible, right?

Or have I totally misunderstood the question?

Comment: I think that any time one writes an equation like $a_1b_2b_3=a_2b_1b_3$ it is assumed that the $b_3$ on the left side of the equation is the same as the $b_3$ on the right side of the equation, in which case your first response is valid.

Comment: In other words: random variables are *functions*, not numbers, and your constraints bear upon these functions.

Comment: Thank you, @GerryMyerson and @Did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument involving $a_1a_2a_3(b_1b_2b_3)^2$ is correct.

The vector $(a_1,a_2,a_3, b_1,b_2,b_3)$ can take $2^6=64$ possible values. ($\pm 1$ for each variable).  The constraint limits the set of values that we are allowed to those that satisfy $a_1b_2b_3=a_2b_1b_3=a_3b_1b_2 = 1$. Sp there are only $8$ possible values that satisfy this constraint. (we are free to choose $b_i$ however we like, but this fixes the $a-i$.)

Your probability distribution then assigns a probability to each of these $8$ vectors, and $0$ to the remaining $56$.

So all you have to show is that $a_1a_2a_3 = 1$ for all $8$ possible values.  Which you've already done.